# Is there a way for me to assign variable numA inside a method defined by scanner class and use it in different methods?

Tags: java, static

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A {
  static void aValue1(){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter value of a: ");
     double numA = scan.nextDouble();
  
  static void aValue2(){
  System.out.println(numA);}
  
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    aValue1();    
    aValue2();
  }  
}
```

I understand that numA is a local variable and can not be used again in a different method, but is there any way I declare numA as static outside of the method and still be able to get the user input for it?

I want the user to type what numA is and I want to use it in every method.

Comment: I guess you are very new to software development. Your next step should be to learn how to write a method, that returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you could have `numA` as a static field

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A {
  static double numA;
  static void aValue1(){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter value of a: ");
     numA = scan.nextDouble();
  
  static void aValue2(){
  System.out.println(numA);}
  
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    aValue1();    
    aValue2();
  }  
}
```